How to split large integers without converting to a string?
I ran into a problem when trying to convert a 5,000 digit long integer into a string.
I realised that I did not need an integer in that case, but I would still like to know if there is a way to manipulate integers without converting it to a string.
As an example, if I wanted the first 10 digits of a large integer using the slice operator:
x = 78**100000000

z = str(x)[:10]
print(z)

This would give me an error for trying to convert an integer of length exceeding 4,300 to a string.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Do you only know x, or do you know a and b such that a ** b == x? If so, you can compute 10**(b * math.log10(a)); floating-point precision should be adequate for only 10 digits.

Conversion to a string  is actually the right thing to do here, because integers don't have digits, only their string representations in a particular base do. (You just don't necessarily want to work with the integer a**b, though, but something else based on a and b, as described above.)

@chepner Using a power was just my suggestion for a compact example.

You can use sys.set_int_max_str_digits(100000):
import math, sys

sys.set_int_max_str_digits(100000)

def get_digits(num, n):
    divisor = 10 ** (math.ceil(math.log10(num)) - n)
    return num // divisor


x = int('9' * 5000)
print(get_digits(x, 10))


Prints
9999999999

Comments

suppose set_int_max_str_digits isn't needed if str() is not used? – mkrieger1

Even if we don't use str() and directly use an int of more than 4300 digits, we do need to set a higher set_int_max_str_digits.



Yeah, my IDE gave me that solution, but it feels like I am not solving the problem, I am just making it less likely to happen.
Is there a way to manipulate integers without changing the type to string first?

@Qmrl You can use math library, bitwise operations, etc. to manipulate integers.

I suppose set_int_max_str_digits isn't needed if str() is not used?

Okay, but it's not needed for finding the leading digits of an already existing integer.

@mkrieger1 It is only needed if we have an integer number with 4301 digits or more.
